# Ubuntu touch threads priority; Will Touch be as laggy as Android, or smooth like IOS?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, performance

Are there separate **User Interface** and **Rendering Threads** in Ubuntu Touch? In other words, will Ubuntu Touch be laggy like android or smooth like ios?

Comment: Who said anything about iOS being smooth?? I find it to be as laggy as hell while Android is blazing fast. Also, every single hardcore Androider is now very offended at your statement.

Comment: @Mew Perhaps he is referencing earlier android devices. I very much recall watching my HTC dream perform terribly slow compared to the Iphone at the time. Havn't really used android since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my memory serves me properly, Ubuntu Touch is based off of Mir and Android. I believe it works the same way as Android does (or at least it did in Surfaceflinger).

However, I have been using it for a while and have seen no lag whatsoever. My (old) iPod lagged much worse though. Must have been all of those "fancy desktop effects" Apple programs in.

They are (as I know) **separate**.

Answer (score 0):

From the mouth of Mark Shuttleworth:

> With regard to Android I think we have two strong stories. One is a really crisp user experience that was designed from the beginning with this full vision of convergence in mind. That is something that is really difficult to achieve with Android today. We know many people who have tried to create clamshell devices with Android and there are lots of reasons why they've struggled. We have very high regard for the Android team's capabilities but we have a different vision when it comes to the convergence story.
>
> The feedback we've had from operators and in user testing is that for
>   a crucial portion of the market, which is the [low-end] smartphone
>   market, the users who today just essentially only make calls and send
>   SMS, that Ubuntu offers a much easier and understandable path to grow
>   those users toward using the Web and e-mail on their smartphones.
>   That's very important for operators. At the low end of the market I
>   think we have a real user advantage experience over Android.
>
> At the high end we have the great fortune to be coming to market late,
>   in the sense that Moore's Law has given us at least seven or eight
>   generations of performance improvements since Android came to market
>   and we've been able to take advantage of that. It's the full Linux,
>   it's essentially Unix in your pocket. That means all the security
>   stories that are true of desktop and server Ubuntu are true of the
>   phone, it means the multi-user story is there, it means the
>   application containment story is there, using Linux containers and
>   virtualization. **It means the parallel SMP [symmetric multi-processing]
>   multi-core story is there from the beginning.** You can do things with
>   Ubuntu devices on the high end that just wouldn't be possible with
>   Android.

Another advantage cited by Shuttleworth is the ability to run "native apps, **whereas Android has the overhead of Java."**

Here is the article I grabbed this from:

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/01/why-mark-shuttleworth-thinks-ubuntu-on-phones-will-outclass-android/